# WHM RAM usage amount needed?

Tags: web-hosting, server, cloud-hosting, whm

I currently have a cloud server that is overkill for my use. When I talk to my hosting company they give me the run around because they do not want me to downgrade (and they lose money.)

My question is:

How do I determine how many processors and RAM I truly need? What info from my WHM account can I provide one of you to help me determine the best server setup size?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you only have WHM access, go to **Server Information** and then to **Current Memory Usage**. That will give you a number to understand what you are consuming at the moment. I think it's a snapshot view, so try to take different measurements to understand how much you are consuming on average.

You can always rent a new VPS that you can scale as you need more or less resources. For example, *Digital Ocean, Amazon,* and others allow you to start with a limited configuration, and scale upwards to a more powerful plan (or reduce an existing one if necessary) as you adjust your needs (or budget).

**Other Notes:**

Processors are about **speed**. In general, the more processors you have, the more powerful the server is. But it is only a general rule, since there are slow performing processors and high-performing ones. Other things to consider with speed are the disks (NVMe SSD is faster than SSD alone), and that your app and database are tweaked for performance.

**Memory** is about how many parallel items you can have running in the server. Fortunately, most programs allow you to limit their memory consumption to a certain max. Know that it's a real headache configuring VPS servers under 1 GB in RAM (doable, but difficult). I often try to get at least a 2GB or upward plan. (YMMV).